# Is there any way to decode to_address from getTransaction(hash).input of a token transfer?

Tags: web3js, transactions

Here is my code,

```
web3.eth.getTransaction(txns.transactionHash,function (err,res){
  console.log(res.to); // consoles contract address
  var input = res.input,erc20=input.slice(0,10);
  if(erc20 == '0xa9059cbb'){
    var amount= web3.utils.hexToNumberString(input.slice(74,138));
    amount = web3.utils.fromWei(amount);
    var to_address = web3.utils.hexToString(input.slice(10,74)); // Cannot get/decode to_address
    console.log(amount,to_address);
  }
})
```

Also, `res.to` consoles contract address instead of exact to_address. So that I'm trying to get it from input hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `to` reffers to the recipient of the transaction (the contract). Token transfer is an "internal transaction" to get the values you need to look into the data (or input) fields.

For instance, using 
`hash = 0x080f0be5e0808320ac80a60646cb43ea1573731f818477710bfbbd377ff81be7`
`web3.eth.getTransaction(txns.transactionHash,function (err,res){console.log(res.input)})`

will give you: `"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000004f2161c7eb1dc40d6f0eb24db81bf4a6eb0c3f300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000"`

Here:

`a9059cbb` (first 4 bytes) gives you the signature of the method transfer

The next 32 bytes are for the address (to) - remove the first 12 bytes (24 zeros)
`0000000000000000000000004f2161c7eb1dc40d6f0eb24db81bf4a6eb0c3f30`

The remaining 32 bytes are the value of the transaction (in Hex)
`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000`

This is because the transfer method is `transfer(address to, uint256 value)`

In general,for ERC20 transfers you can do:

`method =  input.slice(2,10) = "a9059cbb"`

`to = input.slice(34,72) = "4f2161c7eb1dc40d6f0eb24db81bf4a6eb0c3f"`

`value = input.slice(73,138) = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you've heard about the [ethers js](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-advanced.html#interface) library, it provides a fantastic function named **[parseTransaction](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-advanced.html#parsing-objects)**
I found it to be by far the best for decoding any sort of contract and its associated function call.

```
    const ethers = require('ethers');
    const ABI = require('./abi.json'); // Contract ABI
    const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();

    const inter = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI);

    (async() => {
      const tx = await provider.getTransaction('0xa30e9e19967bd3307feeddcf99b26be0d804cdc0ade6929f3b9328a95e388b4c');
        const decodedInput = inter.parseTransaction({ data: tx.data, value: tx.value});

        // Decoded Transaction
        console.log({
            function_name: decodedInput.name,
            from: tx.from,
            to: decodedInput.args[0],
            erc20Value: Number(decodedInput.args[1])
          });        
    })();
```